# How to improve this manifest xml file for passing validation? With the reason `There appears to be an issue in the VersionOverrides element.`?

Tags: office-js

I had submit validation 3 times ... But all of them failed ...

My manifest xml file was generated by VS2017 when I created the word add-in project.

And it works fine in my system.

```
Windows 10 64 bits
Word 2016 with the lastest update
Word online with chrome

VS2017
```

My xml file, please see below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<OfficeApp
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
        xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
        xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

    <Id>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e53e4d4aaxxx</Id>

    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>服务有限公司</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>zh-CN</DefaultLocale>
    <DisplayName DefaultValue="应用名称" />
    <Description DefaultValue="描述" />
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://word.xxxxxxx.cn/Images/icon32x32.png" />
    <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://xxxxxxx.cn" />

    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>https://www.xxxxxxx.com</AppDomain>            
        <AppDomain>https://xxxxxxx.cn</AppDomain>                
        <AppDomain>https://www.xxxxxxx.com</AppDomain>            
        <AppDomain>http://xxxxxxx:111</AppDomain>             
        <AppDomain>https://word.xxxxxxx.cn</AppDomain>             
        <AppDomain>https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.cn</AppDomain>          
    </AppDomains>

    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Document" />
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
            <Set Name="IdentityAPI"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>

    <DefaultSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://word.xxxxxxx.cn" />
    </DefaultSettings>

    <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="Document">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <GetStarted>
                        <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title"/>
                        <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description"/>
                        <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
                    </GetStarted>
                    <FunctionFile resid="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
                            <Group id="Contoso.Group1">
                                <Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label" />
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
                                    <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                                        <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                                        <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>

        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.cn/Images/icon16x16.png" />
                <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.cn/Images/icon32x32.png" />
                <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.cn/Images/icon80x80.png" />
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="Contoso.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html" />
                <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.cn/index" />
                <bt:Url id="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="名称" />
                <bt:String id="Contoso.Group1Label" DefaultValue="点击进入" />
                <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="名称" />
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="文字" />
                <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue=" " />
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

And here are some test results:

```
4.12.1 Your app or add-in must be fully functional
with the supported operating systems, browsers, and
devices for Office 2013, Office 2016, SharePoint
2013, and Office 365.

The add-in is not available to be inserted in the
Word 2016 Client on Windows 10 with Internet
Explorer 11 and in the Word Client on Mac when
using the submitted manifest, however if the
VersionOverrides element is removed, the add-in
becomes insertable without add-in commands. 

This suggests the issue may be in the version
overrides element. For more information on version
overrides and add-in commands, please see:
https://dev.office.com/reference/addins/manifest/versionoverrides
https://dev.office.com/docs/addins/develop/define-add-in-commands
Please see 7.9 below.

7.9 Your add-in’s packages must be correctly
formatted and conform to the current manifest
schema. For Office Add-ins, this is manifest schema
version 1.1.

Your add-in manifest does not conform to the
schema.
There appears to be an issue in the
VersionOverrides element.

Some of the URLs mentioned in your add-in
manifest do not exist. Please ensure all URLs 
mentioned in your add-in manifest exist, including
any mentioned in the description of the add-in.
~remoteAppUrl/Functions/FunctionFile.html
```

I really really confused by it ....

I had read all of the pages that listed in the test details file. But I still don't get the point.

Plese help, I am at a complete loss as to what to do next.

---

- update 1 :

Office Add-In Validator tool. Validate this manifest I got a `Passed`.

```
Calling validation service. This might take a moment...
-------------------------------------
Validation: Passed
Based on the requirements specified in your manifest, your add-in can run on the following platforms; your add-in will be tested on these platforms when you submit it to the Office Store:
  - Word 2016 or later
  - Word Online
  - Word 2016 for Mac
Important: This analysis is based on the requirements specified in your manifest and does not account for any runtime JavaScript calls within your add-in. For information about which API sets and features are supported on each platform, see Office Add-in host and platform availability. (https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability).

*This does not include mobile apps. You can opt-in to support mobile apps when you submit your add-in.
-------------------------------------
```

- update 2 :

I found a example in github, I see no difference with my manifest (without residDesktopFuncUrl) ....

[Word manifest sample in github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/blob/master/Word/manifest/CitationSample.xml#L45)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `remoteAppUrl` in your manifest (In the versionoverrides section), which I believe is a development shortcut in visual studio. You have to replace that with your own server url. Also before submitting your manifest, you can use the [Office Add-In Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-validator) to make sure your manifest is correct.

Comment: Don't "remove" the remoteAppUrl. REPLACE it with the production domain of the add-in.

Comment: Thanks guys! `remoteAppUrl` is one of the problems. I replaced it with my production domain. Office Add-In Validator was useful, I got a `Passed` with my submited manifest.xml file. The result was updated.

Comment: @Zhili that's what I meant :) Edited my answer now!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that If I move

```
<Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set Name="IdentityAPI"/>
    </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

from my manifest.

Then it worked. 
I don't know the reason.